# Where are the blockchain transactions stored?

Tags: blockchain, transactions, blocks

I'm studying the block structure in several blockchains like Bitcoin or Ethereum. When I started to read about blockchain, many sites and books said that transactions are stored in blocks. Ok, I got it, I said to myself. But now I'm not sure to understand it because when I started to read about the block structure, I understood that there are no transactions in a block. In fact, a block contains a list of transaction hashes and the  root Merkle tree/trie of all of these transactions, but the block doesn't contain the transactions themselves, just a reference to each of them. Is this true? If yes, where are the transactions stored if they are not in a block? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean where? Physically or logically? Physically it's in a database but depends on client and how they implemented it. Logically it's just a list of tx with the hash as unique ID that the block can refer to.

Comment: Hi @NicolasMassart, thank you for your answer. Based on your response and as I said, logically, the blocks have just a reference to each transaction they store. But I understand that these transactions are physically stored on a DB or in whatever data structure the client uses. For this reason, it is possible to show the information of whichever transaction. Is that correct? Thank you again.

Comment: Yes it's correct

Comment: Thank you so much, @NicolasMassart. Now I have another question. I think that Merkle trees are necessary inside a block to find if a transaction belongs to a block in an efficient way. But this is because transaction references in a block are stored in an array, and it is impossible to do a direct search in arrays. My question is: If, instead of storing the transactions in arrays, we store them in key-value structures, could we remove the Merkle tree from the block and make blocks more efficient?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't tell you about this optimisation if it's a good idea or not. But I suggest that you discuss this on our Besu Discord: https://discord.gg/hyperledger

If my answer is enough for the first part of your question, please approve it ;)

Comment: @NicolasMassart Thank you for your answers, but now I have another question about Merkle Trees. Is the entire Merkle tree stored inside the block, or is it just computed once, and then the Merkle root is stored in the header? Sorry but websites don't solve these questions. Each website says a different thing.

Comment: I added an answer after our discussion in comments. Please let me know if that answers your initial question and if so please approve it. Thanks.

Comment: @NicolasMassart, Your answer response partially my question. You focus your answer on Besu, which is a private blockchain. What happens in public blockchains like Ethereum? Are the transactions stored in a DB like in Besu? Is the Merkle tree stored in a block or in a place outside the block?

Comment: No besu it totally mainnet client. You can do private chains but anyway we store data the same way.

Comment: As to answer about how it's stored on all clients, you can understand that's a  too broad question as each one has it's own implementation.

Comment: @NicolasMassart Yes, I know that each blockchain implements this in a different way, but I'm searching for how it is implemented in most popular blockchains like bitcoin or Ethereum. Yes, I know that each blockchain implements this in a different way, but I'm searching for how it is implemented in most popular blockchains like bitcoin or Ethereum. Do you know where Merlke trees are implemented in these popular blockchains? Thank you.

Comment: No, not only each blockchain, but also each blockchain client! So for Ethereum, Besu and Geth for instance don't implement it the same way.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. I appreciate it. @NicolasMassart. Based on it, I sense that Merkle trees are stored off-chain, but each client stores it in a different way, but always off-chain. Is this correct? Thank you again.

Comment: Well off chain is not clear what you mean. The chain is the nodes. Nothing exists in the air, it's all on computers. And what computers store IS the chain. They just don't all store the logical chain data the same way. Logic is that the chain is blocks linked together and each block has transaction. It's the yellow paper. After that every node softwar (geth, besu, ...) stores it in the most efficient way according to the programming language and technical choices. Nodes ARE the only place where the chain exists.

Comment: Sorry about my misconception. I referred to off-chain as outside of the block. I suppose the entire Merkle tree is not inside the block itself, but each block stores just the Merkle root. Then the whole Merkle tree is anywhere (because each client stores it differently) outside the block but inside the client HDD. Thank you again.

Comment: I added a link to an article that may be interesting for you in my answer. Nice diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you want to know more about Ethereum tries and storage, you can read https://medium.com/@eiki1212/ethereum-state-trie-architecture-explained-a30237009d4e

Otherwise, if it's just for transactions, for instance for Besu, we store transaction data in a key-value database (RocksDB) and the data is available to be retrieved by the TX hash as the key.

In Besu code, TX are retrieved through the block body storage.

When you ask Besu (for instance using RPC [eth_getTransactionByHash](https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/public-networks/reference/api/#eth_gettransactionbyhash)) it will first look in a key/value table for the hash of the transaction.

This will return the location of the transaction data in the blockchain database.

The location is an object containing the hash of the block containing the transaction data (it also has the transaction position in the bloc for when you ask for eth_getTransactionByBlockNumberAndIndex for instance).

Once Besu has the location of the transaction data, which containes the block hash, it gets the block body from the key/value database where the body is also indexed by its hash.

The body contains the data in RLP format (RLP encoding is a space-efficient object serialization scheme used in Ethereum) and once it is retrieved, Besu decodes this RLP and returns the body as a BlockBody object containing a list of Transaction objects ( a Java `List<Transaction>` actually).

It finally returns the transaction matching the hash requested initially and processes the data either to return transaction info on RPC if you called an RPC method to have transaction info or use it to run the EVM and anything that requires the transaction as an input.